# Make memoryview of bytearray return int elements in Python 2.7

Tags: python

```
b = bytearray(1)
m = memoryview(b)
```

Since the type(b[0]) is int, I would expect type(m[0]) to be int also.  Starting in Python 3.2 this is true.  But in Python 2.7, the type is str.  I need to be able to pass a memoryview to functions which expect an array of int.

In Python 2.7, I could create a wrapper class and override `__getitem__` . But is there a trick to tell a memoryview object to return int elements?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to cause `memoryview`'s `__getitem__` to return `int` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ord` should do the trick:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
>>> b = bytearray(1)
>>> m = memoryview(b)
>>> m[0]
'\x00'
>>> ord(m[0])
0
>>> map(ord, m)
[0]
>>>
```

This is because in Python 2 byte data is stored in strings. Python 3 now [distinguishes bytes and strings](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#indexing-bytes-objects) (unicode).

Comment: But I need to be able to pass a memoryview to functions which expect an array of int, so the receiving function doesn't know that it has to use ord.  I need to take a memoryview object and convert it into something that I can pass to functions which expect an array of int.

Comment: @JeffThompson, use `map` for that. I've added it to the answer